# Strech the BitmapFont in LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I am trying to show the string "Hello" using the BitmapFont. While doing so I wish to scale/strech the word "Hello" horizontally (only in x-axis) from scale 0 to scale 1.

1. How I can achieve this.
2. Does Universal tween engine can be used for this requirement ? I have this question since Bitmap is not a Texture / Sprite.
3. Can we use Glyph and TextBounds

Please advice with a example.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stretch"? Wider letters, or more space in between letters?

Comment: stretch in x axis - Scale the image only in x axis and keep the Y-axis constant

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use free type generator as recommended, you can set scale of bitmapFont vertically and horizontally like this:

`BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
float hScale = 10f;
float vScale = 1f;
font.getData().setScale(hScale, vScale);`

But if you have used free type generator as [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907063/scale-a-bitmapfont-in-libgdx/40739429#40739429), you can do this as below:

```
fontParameter.spaceX = 10;
```